# Compile error building Mono . Have 2.10 installed, complains I need 2.4?

Tags: mono, centos

I am trying to build mono on CentOS. I had problems with not having a proper yum repo, but since have manually installed the rpm from the Suse rpms. Works fine. See output below for versions:

```
 root@localhost mcs]# mono --version
   Mono JIT compiler version 2.11.2 (tarball Thu Jul 12 03:04:31 EDT 2012)
   Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
   [root@localhost mcs]# gmcs --version
   Mono C# compiler version 2.10.6.0
   [root@localhost mcs]# mcs --version
   Mono C# compiler version 2.10.6.0
```

When I try to compile the latest mono, i get the following output... huh? It sees i have it and the version, then complains its not 2.4+.. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
Bootstrap compiler: Mono C# compiler version 2.10.6.0
make[5]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.out] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/root/mono2/mono/mcs'
*** The compiler 'gmcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
*** You need Mono version 2.4 or better installed to build MCS
*** Read INSTALL.txt for information on how to bootstrap a Mono installation.
make[4]: *** [do-profile-check] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/mono2/mono/mcs'
```

Comment: what was your ./configure line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running:

```
make get-monolite-latest
```

resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I ran this after receiving the same error you received and it didn't install anything as far as I know. `mono --version` still says 2.10.12. Any ideas?